# Permission for AWS lambda for executing the Athena query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have created a `worldcities` table in default database in AWS Athena.

Here is the S3 bucket being used:

| Bucket | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| pp-athena-result | for storing the athena results |
| prateek-glue-test | csv files for athena table |

I am trying to execute a select query on Athena table from AWS Lambda using python boto3 SDK. My question is **what permissions are needed by the Lambda function for the query to execute?**

I have created a role with below permissions. `Account-id` is replaced by my account Id:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryResults",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "glue:GetDatabase",
                "glue:GetDatabases",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "glue:GetPartitions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:athena:us-east-1:<account-id>:workgroup/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::pp-athena-result/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::pp-athena-result",
                "arn:aws:s3:::prateek-glue-test",
                "arn:aws:s3:::prateek-glue-test/*",
                "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:<account-id>:catalog",
                "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:<account-id>:catalog/*",
                "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:<account-id>:database/*",
                "arn:*:glue:us-east-1:<account-id>:table/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting the error message:

> table "awscatalog.default.worldcities" does not exist

However once I allowed all actions on s3 bucket i.e.`s3:*` actions, the Lambda function is able to execute the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Athena uses the User's S3 permissions to access the data stored in Amazon S3. Therefore, the IAM User or IAM Role that is calling Athena requires permission to access the data in Amazon S3.

While your policy is granting access to the objects via `GetObject`, it would also require `s3:ListBucket` permission to list the contents of the bucket (otherwise it doesn't know what objects exist!).

Please note that `ListBucket` permission **applies to the bucket itself** so you would need to reference the bucket ARN without the `/*`:

- Action: `s3:ListBucket`
- Resource: `arn:aws:s3:::prateek-glue-test` (which is already in your list of Resources)

See how that goes!